# Apache on mac cannot handle php operator ->

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am new in PHP and setup Apache on my Mac 10.11.5. It was working fine for several days, and now `->` in PHP cannot be correct handled.

In index.php, I have:

```
include UC_ROOT."control/admin/backup.php";
```

In backup.php, I have:

```
include("data/mydb.php");
```

In mydb.php, I have:

```
if(!$this->linkid)    @$this->linkid
```

When Apache renders the PHP page, it displays:

> *linkid) @$this->linkid = mys*

It seems `->` is not recognized correctly.

Could someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Its not the operator you're having problems with. Apache isnt having PHP process anything so your browser is trying to parse PHP as though its HTML. Make sure that Apache/PHP is configured correctly.

Comment: $this only works inside a class...

Comment: @Farkie yes, it is in a class.

Comment: @castis , could you please elaborate it? I have another page: <?php phpinfo();.  It works correctly in the same folder. It seems php is working correctly?

Comment: hmm, is it possible that you're leaving php at some point before the line you're having issues with?

Comment: @X.Hu can you please post more source code surrounding the issue? This sounds more like a typo error than a server configuration error. Also, what version of PHP did you install?

Answer (score 0):

For Apache to parse the PHP code correctly, even inside included files, you still need to include the `<?php` opening tag. Otherwise, Apache will send the PHP code completely unparsed.

It looks like that's the most likely issue, but if it is not please post more source code. This does not sound like an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: Hello btomx, thank you so much! It seems this is the problem. I took the code from someone else, but did not tested it throughly. Is it possible to make Apache to be not so strict on this tag? Thank you again.

Comment: @X.Hu, not really... It's a minor inconvenience, though. It's something you'll have to look out for in the future when borrowing/testing code from the internet. The best you can do is setting `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini file, but all that does is allow you to use `<?` instead of `<?php` to begin your PHP code. It's not recommended since most people do not use this setting. It will make it difficult to share your code with others.

Comment: This is a horrible thing.. but you could auto_prepend_file and add a <?php tag in front of it, hah

Comment: I feel dirty for mentioning that

Comment: @Farkie That won't work. `auto_prepend_file` works like an include; the PHP tag state isn't preserved over includes.